# Magento 2 How to add Delivery date function in both admin and frontend

Tags: date, delivery-date

In magento 2 I need to add Delivery date option in both frontend page and admin page. Is it possible to update by the code?

Comment: Please post whatever you have tried?

Comment: I need to add date option for add product via admin panel